How to sort searchs in Elasticearch using Golang?
I am using the official Elasticsearch library in Go. I am trying to sort the result of a search query but the syntax is throwing an error.
get := client.Search().Index(indexName)
var sort []types.SortCombinations
c := types.SortCombinations{}
get = get.Request(&search.Request{
    Sort: sort,
})

The error is Invalid composite literal type: types. SortCombinations and type of SortCombinations is any.
What should the correct value be so that the sort runs correctly?

Sort should be only desc or asc
example:
sortOrder := "desc" // or "asc"

sort := []types.SortCombinations{
    {
        Field: types.FieldSort{
            Field: sortField,
            Order: &sortOrder,
        },
    },
}


This code does not work. Still getting the same error. Invalid composite literal type: types. SortCombinations Unknown field 'Field' in struct literal
